# How to run Autoware in the Server

Tags: ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I would like to kindly ask whether Autoware.Auto is suitable to be ran on the server. We would like to have a Software-in-the-Loop simulation in the end. However, we met some problems as follows:

1. Two instances cannot stay
   simultaneously in the same ade
   environment. I think this is the
   limitation of ade right? So is it
   better to run the Autoware.Auto
   locally using our own ade and then
   checkout project if there are any
   updates? Or do you have any
   suggestions for project management
   for Autoware.Auto?
2. We try to run the LGSVL simulator on the server per remote desktop but
   failed (aborted (core dumped)). We
   figure out that we would have to
   have a remote desktop session that
   could access the GPU of the server.
   Does anyone know a possible solution
   for this?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/381621/how-to-run-autoware-in-the-server/) by [philiane](https://answers.ros.org/users/77024/philiane/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2021-07-02

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> Two instances cannot stay simultaneously in the same ade environment. I think this is the limitation of ade right?

When you say 2 instances - do you mean 2 instances of Autoware.Auto? If yes, they can perfectly run inside `ade`. https://ade-cli.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ is nothing but just a thin wrapper for easier management of docker images and volumes. As such you can run inside ade anything that you can also run inside the docker container. The way you install Autoware.Auto is either via `ade` or without the `ade`, see: https://autowarefoundation.gitlab.io/autoware.auto/AutowareAuto/installation.html. The advantage of using `ade` is that you can very easily come back to the reproducible environment. Which is more difficult if you develop directly on the host.

> Or do you have any suggestions for project management for Autoware.Auto?

I am not 100% sure what you mean by the project management. Some possible answers:

1. how to develop in Autoware.Auto: https://autowarefoundation.gitlab.io/autoware.auto/AutowareAuto/develop-in-a-fork.html
2. How to run Autoware.Auto CI: https://gitlab.com/autowarefoundation/autoware.auto/AutowareAuto/-/blob/master/.gitlab-ci.yml
3. How to keep track of issues in Autoware.Auto: https://gitlab.com/groups/autowarefoundation/autoware.auto/-/milestones

> We try to run the LGSVL simulator on the server per remote desktop but failed (aborted (core dumped)). We figure out that we would have to have a remote desktop session that could access the GPU of the server. Does anyone know a possible solution for this?

I am not sure what exactly the problem is with your setup. More information would help here. Our problem with the LGSVL simulator is actually this one https://github.com/lgsvl/simulator/issues/1403.

---

Originally posted by [dejanpan](https://answers.ros.org/users/92/dejanpan/) with karma: 1420 on 2021-07-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [philiane](https://answers.ros.org/users/77024/philiane/) on 2021-07-07**:
Thanks a lot for your reply.

Two instances mean that two users are using the same `ade` environment at one server simultaneously. When the second user enters the 'ade', the first one is forced to quit automatically now.